# Is it possible to view the result of the "C++" preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to write a small C++ parser in python (PLY), covering only a small subset of the whole C++ features (no Templates, no Pointers, no operation overloading). I currently have a lot of stuff which works for code snippets, but not for a whole C++ project.
So my biggest problem is to handle the C++ Preprocessor (includes, defines, substitution, ifdef,...).

Does anybody knows a program which gives you the result of cpp-files after preprocessing?

Something which could be called from python would be perfect.

I know it is possible with most of the compilers, but I don't want to include another compiler into my small parser.

I tried boost::wave but it didn't work. Because of :
[Using boost wave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858017/using-boost-wave)

Any hints?

Comment: Yes, `g++ -E`... manuals usually document this sort of information.

Answer (score 2):

The [GNU C preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) is available as a separate program. It works with both C and C++ (and Objective-C).

On my system, it's installed as `/usr/bin/cpp`.

(It's licensed under the GNU GPL; pay attention if you're going to incorporate it into your own project.)

Answer (score -4):

You need to add more library files by adding the following commands.

```
Sudo apt-get install libboost -alt-dev emake subversion
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade
Sudo apt-get install build-essential
Bcc -v
Make -v
Sudo apt-get install git
```

Then you need to restart.
This will work for `.cpp .C .cpp` c++ file extensions .

Comment: `Sudo` and `Make` are spelled `sudo` and `make`, respectively. Is `Bcc` a typo for `gcc`? Why would you need to restart (I presume you mean to reboot the system)? Why do you assume that the OP's system uses `sudo` and `apt-get`? How are `libboost`, `subversion`,  and `git` relevant to the OP's question?